# Which Angular files should I include in a Django project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I'm trying to get the angular 2 official [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) with Django. After doing `npm install`  I get a folder called `node_modules` with 12.523 items and 66 MB. Then, the quickstart writes this references in the html:

```
<!-- IE required polyfill -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>
```

So, I took those files and put them in my django static files. Then, simulated the quickstart in my django rendered html. But I get the error:

> TypeError: _angular_common is undefined

Looks like I'm missing some js files. How can I find wich ones I am missing? should I serve all the 12.523 downloaded items in the node_modules folder? probably not. How can I get the Quickstart working with Django?

This is the Django html just in case:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
    <!-- IE required polyfill -->
    <script src="{%  static 'assets/js/angular/shim.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{%  static 'assets/js/angular/zone.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{%  static 'assets/js/angular/Reflect.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{%  static 'assets/js/angular/Rx.umd.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{%  static 'assets/js/angular/core.umd.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{%  static 'assets/js/angular/compiler.umd.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{%  static 'assets/js/angular/platform-browser.umd.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{%  static 'assets/js/angular/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js' %}"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>

<script>
(function(app){
    app.Component=ng.core.Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        template: "<h1>Lets See...</h1>"
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function() {}
        });
}) (window.app || (window.app = {}));

(function(app) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.platformBrowserDynamic.bootstrap(app.AppComponent);
  });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use bower or other similar project to manage client side libraries.